# Grep only a given number of lines after match

Tags: linux, grep

I need to create a new file from a **grep** match but with maximum number of lines.

Something equivalent to this but one-liner

```
$ cat my_log_file.log | grep -v auto > filtered.log

$ head -n 1000 filtered.log > filtered_1000_lines.log
```

Comment: Does your system's version of `grep` support the `-m NUM, --max-count=NUM` option?

Comment: @steeldriver it does, so the command is `grep -v auto -m 1000 my_log_file.log > filtered_1000_lines.log`

Comment: You say that you want to grep a given number of lines after a match but your code actually prints the last 1000 lines of the file to which you appended the results of `grep -v auto`. More clarity is needed on what you are trying to do.

Comment: @NasirRiley you're right, I'm contradicting myself, so the real command regarding my question is with `head -n 1000 filtered.log > filtered_1000_lines.log`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is

```
$ grep -v auto -m 1000 my_log_file.log > filtered_1000_lines.log
```

Where **-m NUM, --max-count** is the maximum number of matched lines to stop the command, so the **filtered_1000_lines.log** will be feed with the first 1000 matched lines.

Comment: but as per your Q... u require the last 1000 lines...

Answer (score 1):

on one line

```
grep -v auto my_log_file.log | tail -1000 > filtered_log.log
```

(real solution is `-m 1000` if grep allow it)

Answer (score 0):

```
cat my_log_file.log | grep -v auto > filtered.log ;  \
tail -n 1000 filtered.log > filtered_1000_lines.log
```

Either you can combine two commands (can be applied to more than 2 commands even) using `&&` or `;`
(above is written using `;` combination)